# typescript: add properties to a class for alternatives in type

Tags: typescript

I have a type which is a disjunction of strings:

```js
export type Category = 'people' | 'projects' | 'topics' | 'tools'
```

I declare an index as:

```js
interface Entry {
  ...
}
type IPostEntryIndex = {
  [name in Category]: Entry
}
```

How do I declare class properties corresponding to the category names?

```js
const categories: Category[] = ['people', 'projects', 'topics', 'tools']

class PostEntryIndex implements IPostEntryIndex {
  // what goes here so that `PostEntryIndex` has an attribute
  // for each category in Category?

  constructor () {
    categories.map(cat => this[cat] = new Entry())
  }
}
```

**Update**: of course I can simply declare the categories explicitly.
What I'm looking for is a DRY answer, not requiring update if I add
a category. (NB making `categories` array not repeat `Category` would
also be nice. I guess I could use an enum for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no syntax that declares a bunch of properties in a class, so far as I know.  You can add an *index signature* this way, but not a union of string literals.  Obviously you can add them manually, but I presume the point is that you don't want to.

One thing you *can* do is to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) to add the properties into the class instance's interface.  When you write `class PostEntryIndex {}` it creates a value named `PostEntryIndex` which is a class contructor, and an *interface* named `PostEntryIndex` corresponding to the class index.  And you can use interface merging to add whatever properties you want... like this:

```
interface PostEntryIndex extends IPostEntryIndex { }
class PostEntryIndex {
  constructor() {
    categories.map(cat => this[cat] = new Entry())
  }
}
```

Note that doing this circumvents the [strict class property initialization checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization) that comes with `--strict` mode, so you can't rely on the compiler to complain about uninitialized properties.  (This is actually being used to your advantage here, since the compiler does not understand that looping over `categories` serves to initialize all the relevant properties.)

Also note that once you merge the interface in that way, the `implements` clause is particularly redundant so I got rid of it.  (It turns out that `implements` clauses are never really necessary; TypeScript's structural type system does not require you to declare that `A implements B` for you to use an `A` as a `B`, as long as they have compatible structures... but I digress)

Anyway let's see if it works:

```
const pei = new PostEntryIndex();
pei.projects; // Entry
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxFAvFA5JFMAGwlygB88w0UArCAY2AGczLdhCBLB1ivTiiKsA3AFgAUJIZE4zZlACiAO2AYoAbyjMUAWwgAFGmGxQADCKgBfSZNCQoASQMpmwFWpCPlAEwgAPUw1JKCgAbWU4fSguZVgEZHQQAF0ALiVVDEkbKQkGFGU3KAYE1DQuCGZ0+EQykDDk0zD8CEISXAAaKhp6JlYujm5eToEUIVZkkMlYxDQAMzgGaBc3DwxvP0CAxF8FZ1d3TK9fAM1raVl5KBXDzw3T4IlQ-MK1AFcmdAAKAEpNENCxVK6AqzAAdLo4GAviVgNgAHxQYAACy4zDCsMaOGUEAA7hlPL8fgCcjlpAUipAuKYcfibmtjptfuIJFSwdQ6IwWJYAPQ8gkYIA)

Answer (score 0):

The following is accepted by https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

```
export type Category = 'people' | 'projects' | 'topics' | 'tools'

class Entry {
}

type IPostEntryIndex = {
  [name in Category]: Entry
}


const categories: Category[] = ['people', 'projects', 'topics', 'tools']

class PostEntryIndex implements IPostEntryIndex
{
  people: any;
  projects: any;
  topics: any;
  tools: any;

  constructor () {
    categories.map(cat => this[cat] = new Entry())
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry -- question wasn't specific enough. I certain can explicitly declare. The question is how to avoid that?